# Swift 4 wrong date and time

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone, swift4

I am struggle with timezone because I tried to set time to midnight to 23:00:00, however, the result show start with 6am until 5am next day. I tried to set timezone to current, still same result. Here my code

```
let day1num = Int(todaynumber.string(from: Date()))! + 1
let day1start = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .day, value: day1num, of: Date())
let day1end = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 23, of: day1start!)
print("\(day1start!) to \(day1end!)")
```

I got result
**2020-04-22 06:00:00 +0000 to 2020-04-23 05:00:00 +0000**

I don't want 6am to 5am next day, I want result:
**2020-04-22 00:00:00 +0000 to 2020-04-22 23:00:00 +0000**

How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you're misunderstanding `Date` and how it prints to the console.

`Date`s are representative of moments in time. Think of them as an Integer that represents the amount of time that has passed since a reference date. It's NOT a human-readable string. To convert a date to a human-readable string, you need to use a `DateFormatter` and make sure to set the `timeZone` of the date formatter to be the time zone in which you want the string to be representative of (it will default to the system's current time zone). The `timeZone` will impact what the resulting string is. For example, if you have a date formatter where the time zone is Pacific time, it might return a value like `April 22, 2020 6:00 PM`, but then if you change the time zone to mountain time and get the string from the date, it will return `April 22, 2020 7:00 PM`.

When you print a `Date` instance to the console, the system formats it to be a human-readable string in the `UTC` time zone. If I'm doing my math correctly, you're in mountain time, which is why the value you're seeing logged is 6 hours ahead of the value you're expecting.

If you want to see the date logged to the console as the user will see it, you should use a `DateFormatter` instance. It will default to use the user's system time zone, then use the `Date` value you've calculated to get the `String` representation of that date, and then log that `String` to the console, rather than the date itself.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium // Customize as needed
formatter.timeStyle = .medium // Customize as needed
// formatter.timeZone = ... something else if you don't want to use the system time zone
let day1StartAsString = formatter.string(from: day1start!)
let day1EndAsString = formatter.string(from: day1end!)
print("\(day1StartAsString) to \(day1EndAsString)")
```

Comment: You need to set the `dateStyle` & `timeStyle` or the `dateFormat`. Added to the answer above.